# Fix problems with DirectX 9 on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, directx

i tottaly mess up the directX 9 on my system. Trying and trying think i reinstall it but in a very bad way (dxdiag now dont know what version is and directdraw direct3d and aceleration AGP dont work any more)

Do you know a way to clean all this mess? Thanks

Comment: Try reinstalling without uninstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely download the direct X installation tool again. It should fix it. The download you want is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=2da43d38-db71-4c1b-bc6a-9b6652cd92a3). Otherwise, try uninstalling direct X first, and then reinstalling.

Hope that helps.